# Sumar los registros necesarios de una columna de forma que de exactamente 600

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2008

Tengo una tabla con 115 registros, la cual tiene una columna de "precio", sumando todos los campos de esa columna me dan un total de $1000, pero yo necesito sumar únicamente las columnas necesarias para que me den un total de $600. ¿Cómo podría hacer algo así?

Esto es lo que intenté, pero no me funciona:

```
    declare cursor1 cursor for select* from servicio open cursor1 while((select 
    SUM(precio) from servicio)=100) begin fetch next from cursor1 select 
    SUM(precio) from servicio end close cursor1 deallocate cursor1
```

La tabla de 115 registros se ve de la siguiente forma:

```
    id|precio
    -----------
    1 |300
    2 |200
    3 |300
    4 |100
    5 |100
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes aclarar un poco mas que queres hacer? mostrar tus datos? un ejemplo de las cosas que intentaste? el limite es exacto o es hasta eso?

Comment: eso parece un problema matemático, por ejemplo, un número binario, 0110 o 1011, multiplicando por esos números, da como suma 600, 1 * 300 + 0 * 500 + 1 * 100 + 1 * 200 = 600, son 16 combinaciones las que se deberían probar, espero que mi respuesta haya sido útil

Comment: No es tanto un problema matemático, es más sobre una consulta en sql que, de una tabla de 115 registros que sumados dan 1000, seleccione sólo los necesarios para que sumen 600.

Comment: usa el boton [edit] agrega todo lo que te pregunte dentro de tu pregunta

Comment: okei, entendido, yo haría un ´select sum(precio) from productos where precio <= 400` por ejemplo, de esa manera me aproximo y cuando consigo un número cercano, por ejemplo 350, un `select precio from productos where precio <= 350 order by precios`

Comment: Ya quedó editado

Comment: Pero si lo hago de esa forma me va a seguir sumando muchas cantidades y puede que se llegue a pasar de los 600 que necesito y la idea es que lean 600 exactamente o que se aproxime lo mas que pueda pero sin pasarse

Comment: sí amigo, es una aproximación y hay que probar varios valores, de todos modos seguiré trabajando en esa pregunta

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy interesante, pero lamentablemente no puede resolverse muy bien que digamos en SQL. Es un problema de optimización matemática, que puede intentarse resolver con varias aproximaciones: fuerza bruta, búsqueda aleatoria, Búsqueda dirigida por gradientes, programación Lineal, u opciones incluso más esotéricas como algoritmos genéticos. En SQL podrías generar algunas pocas permutaciones (jugando con el orden de las filas) y llegar al número igual o posterior a 600, pero no tendrás garantía que sea la mejor solución.

Comment: Es mas, si hubiera varias formas de sumar 600, cual seria la correcta? esto no es resoluble en sql, no esta preparada para esto, por mas que de casualidad se llegue a un resultado en algun caso en particular

Comment: La idea sería algo como irse sumando desde el primer registro y en cuanto llegue a sumar los $600 que deje de sumar los registros que sobran.
Entonces es mejor jalar todos los registros que tengo y desde código externo(vb en mi caso) intentar sumar hasta que de los 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considero que existe una solución posible; se podría primero ordenar la tabla por precio de forma descendente, así los elementos de mayor precio quedarán al inicio, luego recorrer la tabla sumando los precios hasta que la suma sea menor o igual al total deseado.

Para realizarlo provee primero en **Mysql**, usando una variable para almacenar la suma y mostrarla en una columna, se puede ver el resultado en la demostración.

```
set @sum = 0;
select * 
from (select S.id, S.precio, @sum:= @sum+S.precio as suma
from servicio S
order by S.precio desc) as T
where T.suma<=600
```

<kbd>[`Demostración`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e888ad/2)</kbd>

Luego en el caso de **SQL Server**, se hicieron algunos ajustes ya que el manejo de variables es diferente, en su lugar se uso la función `row_number()`, el resultado es el mismo:

```
select S.id, S.precio
from (
  select row_number() over (order by precio desc) as num, id, precio
  from servicio
) S
where (
  select sum(precio)
  from (select row_number() over (order by precio desc) as num, S3.id, S3.precio
    from servicio S3
) S2
  where S2.num <= S.num
) <= 600
```

<kbd>[`Demostración`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/166e5/1)</kbd>

En ambos casos la sumatoria de los precios de los elementos mostrados es igual al valor esperado (600).

Luego, analizando mas la situación, si se tienen 115 registros que sumados dan 1000, se puede afirmar que en promedio cada elemento tiene un precio de 8 (8.69 para ser mas preciso), por tanto es difícil esperar un resultado exacto, pero con este método se puede tener un resultado aproximado, sin excederse.

Espero haber aportado a resolver el problema, saludos.

Comment: Sin embargo, aun en tu ejemplo, sin ordenar los primeros 6 registros ya sumaban 600... Aunque interesante, esto no se puede resolver efectivamente en sql.

Comment: En efecto, no esperaba un resultado exacto, pero redondeé los números para no hacer tan extensa la pregunta. Tu código hace justamente lo que necesito, darme el numero exacto o en su defecto el más cercano. ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @Azael de nada, fue interesante, que tengas buen día.